# SQL Server Management Studio not showing correct data space of a table

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

### Before

I had a table with 8 columns. The one that is important here is called `SerializedCriteria`. It was text column with **a lot of data**. And by a lot of data I mean over `37000 strings` with length of `20-30 kb` of text.

Anyway this is how the tabled looked like before:

[image: table design before deleting the column]

The size of the table was huge. `37218 records` with total size to more than `1 GB`

[image: table size statistics before deletion]

### Actions

1. I **deleted the column** since I've moved the criteria to another table.
   I am using Entity Framework Code First migrations for making changes to the database.
2. I **shrink** the database and the file of the database
3. I **restarted** Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

### After

Of course the column is removed as I intended:

[image: table design after deleting the column]

The problem is that after the above actions the `size statistics` of the table are **still the same**:

[image: table size statistics after deletion]

### Questions

1. Is the problem in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio or is the deleted column's data is still there?
2. How to see the actual size of the table?
3. If still used, how to remove free the data used from the column. Do I need to somehow shrink or recreate the table?

### Note

The screenshots are with different UI because I've took the screens from production database since in my local SQL Server the changes are already done.

Comment: This question belongs to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Rebuilding the table will most likely fix the problem and free the space

Comment: Rebuilding the table fixed it. Now it is showing correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drop a variable-length column, it is a meta-data only operation so space isn't reclaimed immediately.  You can reclaim the space with DBCC CLEANTABLE (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174418.aspx):

```
DBCC CLEANTABLE(0, N'dbo.YourTable');
```